# Update an object when an other object is within camera view

Tags: unity-game-engine, object, reference, culling, off-screen

I am using a rig which is holding eye objects. My model is moving a lot later on, and for example the head will meet the ground, eyes down there as well.

Now there is a slight problem.

My object's origin is up in the rest pose head position.
If I let the entity move its head down and then zoom in on the eye until I am so close that the origin slips out of my view - the eye is gone, off on vacation. Only when I rotate my view to meet the origin, it reappears. This makes editing and observing difficult. Mind you, it's in *Scene view and Game view* where I observed this situation.

So I thought okay, I can check to update the object when offscreen. But that sounds highly unperformant on hindsight if I do that with each object. Now, there is an object, its main body, which is likely to stay in view more likely, origin wise.
 I wonder. 
Can I pick that other object's origin and determine the update cull with that? There is only a checkbox in my Unity version (2021.3.5f1), not a field to change that, and I am not really experienced in adding fields. So I googled a bit, but I couldn't find a solution, so I thought I ask here.

Edit: I tried this script, added it to the body and dropped in the eye renderer, which is sadly not working as much as I thought. Even though the main body is visible, the eye disappears in both views.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UpdateRendererOverrideManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SkinnedMeshRenderer eye;

    private void OnBecomeVisible()
    {
        eye.updateWhenOffscreen = true;
    }
    private void OnBecomeInvisible()
    {
        eye.updateWhenOffscreen = false;
    }

}
```

[image: script component]

Game view:
[image: eye not rendered]

Comment: Somebody told me that there is something called ``OnBecomeVisible`` and ``OnBecomeInvisible``. I suppose this is a way to go? Not sure how to find the references but that's probably quite easy. 
```
body.OnBecomeVisible(){
eye.m_UpdateWhenOffscreen = true;
}
body.OnBecomeInvisible(){
eye.m_UpdateWhenOffscreen = false;
}```

Comment: `I can't confirm nor negate it happens in Game view.` why not? Just move your camera accordingly..

Comment: I edited my question, apparently it is really a global problem with not being rendered.